# Trying to bake mesh results in "Circular reference in texture stack"

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, texture-baking

I'm trying to bake my object to have a single texture so that I can export it, but I always get a "Circular reference in texture stack" error at the top.

Sometimes it will change to a random image in the UV editor and overwrite parts of my textures, resulting in my object getting warped. I'm using Blender Render.

Is there something I'm missing here? What could be the cause of such an issue?

I've attached my .blend file with all of the textures used to generate it, if that helps any
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Please pack the textures in the blend file instead, then upload it to [Blend-Exchenge](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). Read this post for an explanation of how to pack textures in a blend file: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30906/how-do-i-pack-textures-for-sending-off-to-a-render-farm. And of course, don't forget to [edit] your question to include the new link to the blend.

Comment: Related? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35727/baking-textures-circular-reference-in-texture-stack-error

Comment: @Paul Gonet it didn't solve the issue unfortunately

Comment: Also, whenever I try to bake texture, it will randomly set another one of my textures to black for some reason

Comment: Make sure to carefully choose the image you want for baking output. You can see how to do it [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35727/baking-textures-circular-reference-in-texture-stack-error).

Answer (score 2):

For anyone experiencing the same problem: most likely you are trying to bake to a texture already used by material, even if you see different texture in the UV/Image Editor. Make sure to **select all faces** in the UV editor and then create (Image > New Image) or select the target texture for baking.

[image: UV editor screenshot]

Comment: Also make sure to check if there isn't any texture added to the mesh which uses the same image file as source