# Circular Reference in Texture Stack Error when trying to bake

Tags: modeling, baking

I'm trying to bake some materials, but I keep getting an error named "circular reference in texture stack" when trying to bake it.

Sometimes, a little bit of the texture is baked, but that's it really. When I deleted all the materials, the bake looks like it worked, but it didn't bring any of the texture that I need baked into the UV/Image Editor. I'm running 2.7.9 and need this fixed kinda urgently, so any and all help would be very much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please use the edit link below your question, if you want to add information (such as the blend-exchange link). Comments should not be used to expand the question.

Comment: Fixed, sorry about that. Anyways, any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: Did none of the [many answers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=Circular+Reference+in+Texture+Stack) here on BSE cover your problem?

Comment: No, actually. I tried as many "solutions" as I could find and none of them seemed to of worked for me.

Comment: You may want to check this thread which talk about the same problem :
[Circular reference in texture stack](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35727/baking-textures-circular-reference-in-texture-stack-error)